# How do I move my top panel?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-panel, openbox

I'm running <strike>Gnome-shell</strike> GNOME/openbox, not Unity, on a dual display.

My top and bottom panels are always on my laptop screen. I really want them on the external monitor when that is plugged in. I've read a ton of [tips](https://askubuntu.com/a/21528/13049) about using `gconftool-2` and `gconf-editor` to switch the "monitor" key from 0 to 1 for each panel, but doing that has no effect.

I can use <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>super</kbd> <kbd>right</kbd> to access the panel properties and move the panel to the top / left / right / bottom of my laptop screen, but I can't for the life of me move it over to my external monitor.

I recently rearranged my desk and don't know what all I customized six months ago when I was setting up my desktop environment. So one question is ... could I have done something to give control over my panels to something other than gconf-editor? How would I figure that out?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm if you're using [GNOME Shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Shell) or [GNOME Panel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Panel)?

Comment: I'm not actually running Gnome-shell - I use classic mode, so this may not work at all (hence the comment), but I can move the top panel by doing "alt-meta + right-click", choosing "properties", then unchecking "expand".  I can then drag it with my mouse to where I want it, and reverse the procedure to again check "expand".

Comment: @fluteflute Good point. I logged out and back in to check (is there an easier way to know???) that I'm running GNOME/Openbox. Question updated to reflect that.

Comment: @MartyFried BINGO! That works. I even edited my question to stave off the "alt-meta-right" tips, and then I read your comment again. I'd still love to understand what is going on here, but if you want to post your comment as an answer I'll definitely accept it.

Comment: @Amanda - OK, thanks, I made it an answer.  Glad it worked for you - it's always nice to be able to make things work the way you want - or at least, the way you _think_ you want.  :)  As for understanding what is going on, I'm not sure I know which part you don't understand.  Hopefully, it's not _why_ it can't be dragged when expanded, because I don't actually know.  Please don't ask me how I knew to even do that; somehow, I just knew from past experience somewhere.

Comment: @MartyFried I think it's precisely "why can't I drag an expanded panel" but I doubt the answer is entirely technical.

Comment: Now that I look at it, I see I misled you.  You actually **can** drag an expanded panel, as long as you can find a place on the panel that isn't covered by an added item.  When unexpanded, it's easy to grab the "handles" at either end, but when expanded, you can still drag if you click in the right place (using super-alt **left**-click to drag.  Sorry for the incorrect information.  There, are you happy now?!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not actually running Gnome-shell - I use classic mode, but I can move the top panel by doing "alt-super + right-click", choosing "properties", then unchecking "expand". I can then drag it with my mouse to where I want it, and reverse the procedure to again check "expand".

Answer (score 8):

On my Gnome 3.8.4 (Ubuntu 13.10) the right way to do that operation was going in monitor settings, and drag&drop the *panel* from the monitor to the other one (pointing the cursor on the little monitor pictured in the image box).

Here's a screenshot (sorry, the user interface is not in english):

[image: Screenshot of the operation]

Comment: This dialog is now long gone from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

For Ubuntu 20.04 desktop version, you can go to `Settings` -> `Display` and in the
**Primary Display** field, pick the particular monitor you want to be the primary and the top bar will move to that screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To do anything with panel the key combination is `win+alt+click`. Do that and you will get properties option.You can easily configure it after that.

Comment: I can move the panel to the top/bottom/right/left of my laptop screen with super-alt-click, but I can't move it from my laptop to my external monitor.

Comment: well with unity i get it on both of the screens,with gnome panel i think you should check it with your graphics card settings or the monitor settings in system settings.